# How to copy "this" from constructor JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, closures

I'm trying to make a copy of `this.card` from the `constructor`.  But, so far it does not work. Maybe this is not possible. Anyway, can someone tell me how to do this?

```js
class CardList {
  constructor(card) {
    this.card = card;
  }

  render(container, cards) {
    this.container = container;
    this.cards = cards;

    this.cards.forEach(card => {
      this.card.placeImage.setAttribute(
        "style",
        `background-image: url(${card.link})`
      );

      this.card.placeName.textContent = card.name;
      this.container.appendChild(this.card.placeCard);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily deep clone an object with [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep).

Try this:

```
this.anotherCard = _.cloneDeep(card);
```